# JS Fs.readfile works after the bottom code executed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm newbie at JS, and I didn't understand a thing.
The problem is, I have a `fs.readfile` function, and there is `while(1){//code}` code execution bottom of it.

***The example:***

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
let fs = require('fs');

function aFuncName() {
  let nms;
  fs.readFileSync('filename.txt', (error, data) => {
    console.log('readfile began!')
    if (error)
      console.log(error);

    try {
      nms = data.toString().match(/\n/).length
        console.log('ind:' + String(ind))
    } catch (TypeError) {
      nms = 0;
    }
    console.log("readfile over!");
  });

  let userarry = [nms]
  while (1) {
    let vars = prompt('varsm):')
  }
}
```

the problem is, the function passes the `fs.readfilesync` part and begins from `let userarry`.
I also tried `fs.readFile`

Comment: [`readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) does not take a callback function but returns the file content directly. And if you change to [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback) read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron